# Get top N rows of each group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given a MySQL table of the form

```
Name   | Type
-------+-----
Bill   | A
Hill   | B
Jill   | C
Hans   | A
George | C
Sophie | B
Hannah | B
Nancy  | C
Phil   | A
...    | ...
```

I would like to produce a MySQL query which provides me with the top `N` rows grouped by their type. By 'top' I mean with respect to a given ordering. In this example, it could be the order given by ordering the type parameters alphabetically (or by date, if all type parameters are dates). For instance, if `N = 2`, then the resulting table could be:

```
Name   | Type
-------+-----
Bill   | A
Hill   | B
Jill   | C
Hans   | A
George | C
Sophie | B
...    | ...
```

That is, the entries may very well be grouped into their respective types in the resulting tables, but it is not strictly important that they are. I run MySQL 8.x.

Comment: I don't see what `. . .` is supposed to mean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It was my way of indicating that the table could have more entries.

Comment: Define 'top'. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `n` rows per group, use `row_number()`.  If you then want them interleaved, use `order by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
order by seqnum, type;
```

This assumes that "top" is alphabetically by `name`.  If you have another definition, use that for the `order by` for `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` as whown below.

In my case, the table name was `company_perform_quter`. I used group by single column, order by multiple column and received latest four record for each group.

```
SELECT* from (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY symbol, year DESC, month DESC, quater DESC) rowNum
FROM company_perform_quter) nn WHERE rowNum<=4
```